# Could there be a better classification of finite simple groups?

Tags: soft-question, finite-groups

The current classification of finite simple groups puts every finite simiple group in one of a few categories. There are the "nicely" behaved infinite categories (cyclic, alternating, Lie-type) and then there are the leftover "sporadic" groups. As formulated in the wonderful [3Blue1Brown Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE&t=14s): "That a field of study rooted in symmetry itself has such a patched together structure [...] is just bizarre."

This made me wonder, whether there is any reason that a classification has to have this kind of "patched together" structure or whether we just have not found the "correct" underlying structure of finite simple groups.

Comment: How do you feel about the periodic table of atoms?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, I would debate the quote from the video that you link to. The periodic table of atoms is not super-elegant (what's up with all those lanthanides?) but it is what it is. Why should one hope to avoid sporadic simple groups?

Comment: On a more positive note, my understanding as a spectator is that some of the finite simple groups which are not technically "Lie type" can somehow be philosophically regarded as "like groups of Lie type" but I'm afraid I don't know the details. However, I don't think anyone has claimed that this will encompass all of the sporadics.

Comment: Most of the sporadics fit into the “three generations” of the “happy family.” That is, there’s three exceptional structures: the Golay code, the Leach lattice, and the Monster Lie Algebra, each of which is constructed using the previous one, and most sporadic simple groups are related to the automorphism groups of these three structures.

Comment: Such a question (as in the title) is only answerable (positively) in retrospect, and it is impossible to answer in the negative.

Comment: One can ask a similar question for the complex semi-simple Lie algebras, where our understanding is much better. What's with $G_2$ and $E_6, E_7$ and $E_8$!? There are various attempts to understand things "coherently" (Freudenthal's magic square etc.) but my suspicion is that the wonder will always remain! I find the balance between classical groups and exceptional groups fascinating and even more beautiful :)

Comment: I remember reading something somewhere that claimed some researchers were of the mind that the (sporadic) simple groups were really just shadows of some other mathematical structure, and they were just the ones that just happened to be groups.  Monstrous Moonshine was, I think, taken as a suggestion that they were really the "shadows" of certain vertex algebras.  Seems a bit like passing the buck to me. I've usually held the general philosophy that at small "orders" there's not enough room to be interesting, while large orders have too much room, leaving a goldilocks zone for "sporadics".

Comment: This question reminds me of Sabine Hossenfelder's criticism of SUSY as a model for physics. Just because it's pretty doesn't mean it's right, and just because it doesn't seem pretty enough doesn't mean we're missing something.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson That's an excellent analogy to consider. Let me venture the opinion that we have some evidence that sporadicness is inescapable, because different sets of objects show up depending on what question we ask. For example, if we ask for all finite Coxeter groups then some additional groups creep in, and there are other questions where the answer is A-D-E. If there were some grand unified theory, then we might expect the same answer to all questions. So we might ask, if we pose a slightly different question, do we get a different set of finite groups showing up?